Como seleccionar la fecha y hora de inserción en oracle mediante una consulta?
espero y me puedan ayudar por favor, lo que pasa es que quiero obtener la hora que fue insertados registros a la bd, tengo este query:
select * from complemento_pago_fact where
TO_DATE(FECHA_CREACION,'DD/MM/YY') = '30/04/24';

Pero solo muestra la pura fecha, quiero que se muestre una hora en especifico por ejemplo a las 17:40, espero y me brindar algunos ejemplos por favor, se los agradeceré mucho, si hay algo que no se entienda con gusto lo explicaré. Saludos.

Hay que revisar siempre la documentación...

El nombre de la columna "fecha_creacion" sugiere que la columna solamente contiene la fecha sin hora. Si es así, no puedes seleccionar la hora, porque es desconocido ;-) (Bueno, la hora será 00:00:00, porque en Oracle no hay un tipo de data para una fecha sola, siempre contiene un parte para la hora, pero cuando lo usamos para guardar fechas, lo hora es medianoche.)
Si el nombre está descarriando, y la columna no contiene una fecha, sino fecha y hora, puedes seleccionarlo y mostrarlo.
Seleccionar filas con una fecha con/sin hora
Esto es lo que haces:
WHERE TO_DATE(fecha_creacion, 'DD/MM/YY') = '30/04/24'

Bueno, ojalá "fecha_creacion" es un DATE. ¿Qué hace TO_DATE usado con un DATE? TO_DATE es una función que recibe una cadena de caracteres (VARCHAR2 típicamente) para tratar de convertirlo a un DATE. Así que "fecha_creacion" ya es un DATE, el DBMS tiene que convertirlo a un VARCHAR2 al principio. Entonces lo que pasa es
WHERE TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(fecha_creacion), 'DD/MM/YY') = '30/04/24'

Entonces el DBMS convierte tu DATE a un VARCHAR2, ¿pero en qué formato? ¿'DD/MM/YY' o 'MM/DD/YY' o 'DD.MM.YYYY' o ...? Esto depende de la configuración de tu sesión. Si es 'DD/MM/YY', tu TO_DATE va a funcionar, si es 'MM/DD/YY' puede funcionar, pero resultar en una fecha equivocada. Y si es otro formato es muy probable que la consulta va a producir un error.
Supongo que quieres hacer esto:
WHERE TO_CHAR(fecha_creacion, 'DD/MM/YY') = '30/04/24'

Es decir, convertir la fecha a una cadena de caracteres que quieres comparar con '30/04/24'.
Es más simple desechar la hora y comparar con una fecha:
WHERE TRUNC(fecha_creacion) = DATE '2024-04-30'

El único problema con esto: Si tienes un index para encontrar una "fecha_creacion" rapidamente, este index no va a funcionar, porque no buscas una fecha_creacion, pero una TRUNC(fecha_creacion). Por esto solemos hacer esto para seleccionar fechas:
WHERE fecha_creacion >= DATE '2024-04-30' AND fecha_creacion < DATE '2024-05-01'

(Naturalmente, si "fecha_creacion" solamente contiene fechas sin horas, puedes usar WHERE fecha_creacion = DATE '2024-04-30' en vez.)
Si quieres seleccionar un momento particular, por ejemplo, el minuto 12:34:56:
WHERE fecha_creacion >= TIMESTAMP '2024-04-30 12:34:00'´ AND fecha_creacion < TIMESTAMP '2024-04-30 12:35:00'

Mostrar una fecha con/sin hora en los resultados
Solamente tienes que hacer
SELECT fecha_creacion

El resultado va a tener la fecha y la hora. U en el caso que la columna solamente contiene una fecha, el resultado va a ser la fecha con 00:00:00. En el programa que ejecuta la consulta (una aplicación, un sitio de Web) puedes elegir si quieres mostrar la hora o no.
Puedes usar TO_CHAR para convertir la fecha en una cadena de caracteres, pero esto es algo que casi nunca hacemos, porque queremos que nuestro programa sabe que es una fecha (y entonces sabe cómo ordenar los datos por ejemplo). Pero si usamos la consulta para producir un fichero, usamos TO_CHAR para que el fichero contiene las fechas (y horas) en el formato que deseamos. Por ejemplo:
SELECT TO_CHAR(fecha_creacion, 'DD/MM/YY')

o
SELECT TO_CHAR(fecha_creacion, 'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI')

Si estas usando un herramienta, como el SQL Developer, está en la configuración del programa si te muestra la fecha con o sin hora. En este caso también puedes usar TO_CHAR para verlo en el formato que deseas.

Lo de usar TO_DATE sobre una columna de tipo DATE para comparar contra un string que representa una fecha en algún formato es resultado de un entendimiento equivocado de como es que Oracle almacena y maneja un valor tipo DATE, ya que la persona cree que como "ve" la fecha-tiempo en su herramienta de consulta o IDE es como Oracle lo almacena,.
